# How to connect to task inside a cluster on AWS ECS via Postmann?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, docker, networking

I am trying to run a flask app inside a docker container on AWS ECS. I created a task and assigned it to a cluster, but now I cannot ping the public ip adress of this task.

I also cannot send the request via POSTMANN as it was possible when I ran the docker container from the same image on my local machine. Any help is highly appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

After two weeks I finally found the answer to this problem! If you run your task inside the awsvpc, you need to create an inbound rule, which states the ip adress from where you want to send the POST request with Postman. After setting up the rule, the aws task inside the cluster can be accessed.